# Any example code for NSUserActivity in SearchApi feature?

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, ios9, itunes-search-api, ios-9-beta3

Can anybody please provide me tutorial or example code in NSUserActivity feature for SearchApi. I am doing lots of RND about this feature but didn't get proper code for this.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/task_management/continuing_user_activities_with_handoff

Answer (score 2):

An example would be:

```
let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "com.tutsplus.iOS-9-Search.displayShow")
activity.userInfo = ["name": detailItem.name, "genre": detailItem.genre, "time": detailItem.time]
activity.title = detailItem.name
var keywords = detailItem.name.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
keywords.append(detailItem.genre)
activity.keywords = Set(keywords)
activity.eligibleForHandoff = false
activity.eligibleForSearch = true
//activity.eligibleForPublicIndexing = true
//activity.expirationDate = NSDate()

activity.becomeCurrent()
```

See [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-introducing-search-apis--cms-24375) for more information and examples

Comment: Thanks for help, but this code is not working...after trying this i use to post my question here.

Comment: This code is working for me, and the link provided in the answer shows how to implement it.